# AVPlayer takes long time to start audio play

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I have a music player which streams audio from server, using `AVPlayer`, it plays a audio well, but  after completion of an audio , when i click play button for new  audio it takes time to start new audio almost 35-40 sec. Can anyone help me?

Comment: post some code where you are getting delay or ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use observer to know the player state.
Using KVO, it's possible to be notified for changes of the player status:

`playButton.enabled = NO;
player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileURL];
[player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];`

This method will be called when the status changes:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
if (object == player && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
    if (player.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
        playButton.enabled = YES;
    } else if (player.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
        // something went wrong. player.error should contain some information
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Even AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay, i play the audio, i have 5 secs with delay and time is NAN... it is normal ?

Comment: Can i please have swift version for this